# Question on Lebesgue Integration (from old qual)

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

This problem is from an old real analysis qual...I am trying to review some material I just finished concerning Lebesgue Integration. Below is the problem followed by my attempted (unfinished) solution. Any help towards showing the problem holds would be great.

*Problem:*

Show that for all integrable functions $f$ over $\mathbb R$ that

$$\lim_{\delta \to 1}\int\left\vert f(\delta x)- f(x) \right\vert dx = 0.$$

---

(My attmpted) *Solution:*

Let $\delta_n\in\mathbb{R}$ be a sequence such that $\delta_n\to 1$. Consider the sequence of functions $f_{n}\colon \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by,

$$f_{n}:= |f(\delta_nx)-f(x)|.$$

This is where I get stuck and I am unsure if I should go down this route. However, if this route is correct, then the following would be the final step.

Thus,

$$\lim_{\delta \to 1}\int\left\vert f(\delta x)- f(x) \right\vert dx = 
\lim_{n \to \infty}\int\left\vert f(\delta_n x)- f(x) \right\vert dx = 
\int\lim_{n\to\infty}\left\vert f(\delta_n x)- f(x) \right\vert dx = 
\int\left\vert f(1\cdot x)- f(x) \right\vert dx = 
\int 0 = 0$$

Comment: maybe you could start by $L^1$ approximating $f$ with a continuous compactly supported function?

Comment: @Timkinsella: I am not aware of such methods--all I have covered is (basic) Lebesgue Integration over $\mathbb{R}$ from Royden. However, since this is taken from an old real analysis qual, such methods may be necessary and I might be trying to tackle a problem without the proper tools...

Comment: in my copy of Royden there are approximation theorems in section 6.4. Prop 8 there tells you what I said without "compactly supported" but that is an easy extension.

Comment: @Timkinsella I have not gotten to chapter 6 yet, but I checked and I do not see a Prop 8 in section 6.4. I have the 4th edition, and section 6.4 covers "Absolutely Continuous Functions".

Comment: Oh yeah i have 3rd ed. the section is titled "approximation in $L^p$"

Comment: @Timkinsella: Oh, I see. For the 4th edition, section 7.4 is is titled "Approximation and Separability". However, I am a good ways from starting that material. I suppose I'll come back to this problem once I finish such section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a proof which does not require approximation by continuous functions:

Let $A \Delta B$ denote the symmetric difference between $A$ and $B$: $A \Delta B=(A\setminus B) \cup (B\setminus A)$. Consider the collection of all Borel sets $A$ such that $m((tA)\Delta A)\to 0$ as $ t \to 1$.  [$tA=\{ta: a \in A\}$].

It is easy to check that this collection contains all intervals.

Use the fact that $(\bigcup_n A_n) \Delta (\bigcup_n B_n)  \subseteq \bigcup_n (A_n\Delta B_n)$ and $A \Delta B=A^{c} \Delta B^{c}$  to verify that our collection is a sigma algebra.

It follows that every Borel set belongs to this collection.

This can be written as $\int |f(\delta_n x)-f(x)|dx \to 0$ when $f=\chi_A$. Extend this to simple functions and then to all integrable functions $f$.